# How to adjust the width length of g:field type="number" in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I tried the ff:

```
 <g:field type="number" name="refNumber" width="100 px"/>

 <g:field type="number" name="refNumber" size="100"/>
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a style:

```
<g:field type="number" name="refNumber" style="width: 100px"/>
```

or even better class:

```
<g:field type="number" name="refNumber" class="yourClass"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to to with grails, but just plain HTML. "100 px" should not have a space. It should be like,

```
<g:field type="number" name="refNumber" width="100px"/>
```

Comment: are there any css styles that are overriding the width?

Comment: none, but I added a css  #refNumber{
        width:100px;
} and it's ok now.. Thank You..